# Convert a number to a string representation in scala without using toString()

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I need to convert an integer to a List of Int that comprises of all the digits in that Int. I camp up with the following (*using toString is forbidden*)

```
def Int2Str(n: Int): String = {
    val digit2Char = Map(
      0-> '0',
      1-> '1',
      2-> '2',
      3-> '3',
      4-> '4',
      5-> '5',
      6-> '6',
      7-> '7',
      8-> '8',
      9-> '9'
    )
    var  tmp  = n
    var sb = new StringBuilder()
    while(tmp> 0){
      sb.append( digit2Char(tmp % 10))
      tmp = tmp/10
    }
    sb.foldRight("")((p,n)=> n :+ p)
  }
```

Example:

- `Int2Str(2312) => "2312"`
- `Int2Str(345690) => "345690"`

My questions:

1. Is there a better way to do it in a more functional style without
   using var?
2. Is using var a very bad practice in Scala as written in articles often? then why we have var in the first place?

Comment: Why is `toString` forbidden? This does not look like a genuine problem.

Comment: What is a "genuine" problem? can you explain

Comment: In the subject line you ask: "How to create a list of digits (int)". However, in your example code, you return a string. A string is definitely *not* a list of digits.

Comment: I guess what Tim means with that comment, is that it is *extremely* unlikely that a professional programmer in their career will encounter a real-world problem in a real-world codebase where it is somehow impossible to use `toString`. Therefore, it is likely that there are some artificial constraints on your problem that you haven't really told us about. Artificial constraints, however, are not terribly interesting to the programming community at large, since they tend to only apply to one single problem of one single person. The goal of [so], however, is to build a knowledge base for *all*.

Comment: Your method returns the empty string for `0` as well as for all negative numbers. Is that intentional?

Comment: if you input zero it returns "0" i have not considered neg numbers.

Comment: @SimpleFellow: "if you input zero it returns "0"" – No, it doesn't. It returns the empty string: `Int2Str(0) //=> ""`.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag I changed the title, thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag this isn't the final version but that's not the point. the point is is there any possible way to get rid of var and while loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to allow for the full range of `Int` values.

```
def int2str(num :Int) :String = {
  val ll = LazyList.iterate(math.abs(num))(_ / 10)
  val res = (ll.head +: ll.tail.takeWhile(_ > 0)).map(n => (n % 10 + 48).toChar)
                                                 .reverse
                                                 .mkString
  if (num < 0) "-" + res else res
}
```

testing:

```
int2str(0)             //res0: String = 0
int2str(Int.MaxValue)  //res1: String = 2147483647
int2str(-27)           //res2: String = -27
```